# populating a RecyclerView in a Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dialog, adapter

**I have found a solution and its attached as an answer**

I'm currently having trouble populating a layout in a dialog with information from my adapter. The data is fetched from the API and passed into my data class but since the recyclerview that I'm trying to reference is in the Dialog's layout file, not in the file i'm using to call said dialog, the view just returns an null.

Here is my code for context.

CheckboxActivity.kt (Just the callback) ***people_list is returning null***

```
private val callbackGETUSERS = object : Callback<List<Users>> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Users>>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.e("API-GET-USERS", "Problem GETTING USERS", t)        }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Users>>, response: Response<List<Users>>) {

        val result = UsersResult(response.body() ?: return run {
            Log.e("API-ME", "Problem calling USERS")
        })

        peopleList = result
        people_list.adapter = ManagePeopleAdapter(result)
    }

}
```

d_manage_people.xml (the dialog resource file)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/manage_people_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Subtitle1"
        android:text="Create Item"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/people_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and here is my error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: people_list must not be null
```

By the way I'm using a plugin that allows me to not use findViewById

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Well that means `people_list` is not in the Activity's layout.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah, its not. I was wondering if there was any way to access views that are not in the Activity's layout but in the dialog's layout

Comment: Well not *inside* the Activity :p but what you can do is use the layout inflater to inflate the view, then pass it to the dialog builder with the `.setView()` method, then you can find the view by id on the view you inflated

Comment: @EpicPandaForce would I do that in the callback?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce because I already do all that on an onClick method when a button is pressed


 `fun onPeopleClicked(view: View) {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.d_manage_people, null)
        val userName = view.person_name
        view.manage_people_title.text = "Manage People"
        dataRetriever.getUsers(callbackGETUSERS, getAuth(), listID)
        

        dialog.setView(view)
        dialog.show()
    }`

Yikes that formatted poorly :/

Comment: Don't use synthetics here, they won't work.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I switched it over to a findViewById and it still returns that its null. Should I move the adapter setting from the callback to the onclick function?

Comment: It might seem tacky, but I think that'd work :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happened to be with me not attaching the view's context

Instead of calling the Recycler View in the CallBack like

```
people_list
```

and then setting the adapter from there, I just had the callback call a function that then created the dialog and I used context from that to reach the RecyclerView

```
 val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.d_manage_people, null)
    dialog.setView(view)

    view.manage_people_title.text = "Manage People"

    val adapter = ManagePeopleAdapter(result)
    view.people_list.adapter = adapter
    view.people_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show dialog after API call. Something like below

```
private val callbackGETUSERS = object : Callback<List<Users>> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Users>>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.e("API-GET-USERS", "Problem GETTING USERS", t)        }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Users>>, response: Response<List<Users>>) {
        val result = UsersResult(response.body() ?: return run {
            Log.e("API-ME", "Problem calling USERS")
        })
        peopleList = result
        this@CheckboxActivity.showDialog()
    }
}

private fun showDialog() {
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.d_manage_people, null)
    view.manage_people_title.text = "Manage People" 
    people_list = view.findById(R.id.people_list)
    people_list.adapter = ManagePeopleAdapter(peopleList)
    dialog.setView(view)
    dialog.show() }
}
```

And just call API on button click.

```
onPeopleClicked(view: View) {
    dataRetriever.getUsers(callbackGETUSERS, getAuth(), listID)
}
```

Comment: The problem ended up needing me to append `people_list` with `view`, which would be the dialog's context. Thanks for the help anyways :D